# What JS Syntax is this and what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, methods, syntax

First of all, sorry for the redundant question, just haven't found a proper way to ask this. I was checking out a video for protecting routes using React-router when the dude in the video wrote something like this:

```
class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this.authenticated = false;
  }

  login(cb) {
    this.authenticated = true;
    cb();
  }

  logout(cb) {
    this.authenticated = false;
    cb();
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticated;
  }
}
```

Here's the bit that's confusing me:

```
login(cb) {
  this.authenticated = true;
  cb(); // What syntax is this???
}
```

What does this do exactly do? Is it supossed to take a function as an argument call her? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: "Is it supossed to take a function as an argument call her?" — Yes

Comment: Yes, it's a function call.

Comment: login(cb){
//1st line
cb();//2nd line, this calles the arrow function
}
//from where you call login method
login(()=>{//the paramenter passed in an arrow function.....this will be called when cb() gets executed in login method... 
 console.log('called);
})

Comment: This makes sense, thanks!